# Is there legal precedent when there is no permission granted & a sibling enters your room? They were caught on camera

Tags: trespass, family, singapore

I am interested to know if trespass will be considered if its a family member.

The door was closed & permission was not granted.

There was nothing wrong being done but they just enter & walk around the room.

Would there be legal precedent in Singapore to stop them from coming in?

Comment: Who is the owner or occupier (with full legal capacity) of the premise? Is the sibling also a legal occupier of the premise? Also, something being technically illegal does not make it necessarily actionable; in almost all jurisdictions, a de minimis or public interest or an equivalent consideration gives police, prosecutors, judges discretion to decline exercise of public power.

Answer (score 3):

The applicable Singapore statute is:

[Singapore Statute](https://sso.agc.gov.sg/Act/PC1871?ViewType=Within&Phrase=trespass&PageIndex=0&PageSize=20#:%7E:text=Punishment%20for%20criminal%20trespass%20Whoever,or%20with%20both.%20...)

There it says:

> 441 Criminal trespass ...Criminal trespass Whoever enters into or upon
> property in the possession of another with intent to commit an offence
> or to intimidate, insult or annoy any person in possession of such
> property, or having lawfully entered into or upon such property,
> unlawfully remains there with intent thereby to intimidate, insult or
> annoy any such person, or with intent to commit an offence, is said to
> commit criminal trespass

It seems highly unlikely that the local authorities would consider it trespass if it was done by another person lawfully in the property.